# Compare two hive tables with same columns but different value in data

Tags: hive

A database has two tables table1 and table2.the structure is same for both the tables,

### table1

### name   score1  score2 scorefinal

a        0       1      0

### table2

### name   score1  score2 scorefinal

a        0       0      0

i want to compare2 tables and check if value of table2.score=(table1.score+2)
I want the Hive query to check that

```
enter code here

select count(*)
from test.table2 a,
test.table1 b
where a.score1='2' and a.score2='0' 
and b.score1='2' and b.score2='0' 
and a.scorefinal=(b.scorefinal+2);
```

i want to use in a better way for comparison using joins if possible

Comment: what have you done so far?

Answer (score 0):

select * from

(select *,
case when a.score1 = b.score1 or a.score2 = b.score2 or a.scorefinal=(b.scorefinal+2)
     then 1
   else 0
end as value -- **giving an OR condition here which means if any of one is true then 1, if you need the condition to be true for all the cases you need to keep AND**

from 
test.table2 a,
test.table1 b

) q 
where value = 1